# dnn - adding module to right pane

Tags: dotnetnuke

what am i doing wrong?
i want to add an html module to the right pane with the intent it will show on every page after the single addition tot he pane. the pane is used on every portal page.
when i add the module i needed to do it on a page by page basis.

whats the method to correctly add it to the pane once and have the change reflect everywhere the pane is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module setting for that. I think it is show on all pages or something like that. but you will also need to make sure that you set the module security accordingly as well.

Comment: how do i find out the url to an image i uploaded and intend to use in my html module? i uploaded it via the portal's file manager and cant figure out the url to the image

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head as it has been awhile. Though if you are just using this for a single installation and not a portal system then you can find the image on the hard drive and just figure out the url from there. That would be a hack but would work.

Comment: how do i get the module to sit in the middle of the others?
when i show this module on all pages it takes the top most position and not where i intend for ti to go. i want it 3rd from the top.

Answer (score 1):

Module settings -> Parameters ->

-> Main -> Set View right for all users

-> Additional params -> Set Show on all pages

Save

Comment: this does make the module appear on every page but it takes the first position. there are a series of 6 modules and i want it in the middle (after the 3rd and prior to the 4th) how can i get it to display at the correct spot in the panel on each page and not on the 1st spot on top?